# show and hide elements in for loop with time interval

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create my very first simple board game with JS, and have problem with making pawn seems to be moving.

I have created a board as a 15 x 15 table, in every <td> there is round field with id  crated thanks to <p>:

```
<div class="game-board">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><p class="board-field" id="1"></p></td><td><p class="board-field" id="2"></p></td>...
      </tr>
      <tr>
...
</div>
```

on current field I am displaying pawn graphics with JS:

```
  let pawn = "<i class='fas fa-chess-pawn'></i>";

  document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = pawn;
```

I have a button which is generating random number from 1 to 6 and displaying dice roll animation. After generating dice roll result I am trying to show and hide pawn graphics on fields to show "moving" effect.

In example. 
Step 1. Roll the dice and draw 3.
Step 2. Show pawn on filed with id 1
Step 3. Wait 300ms
Step 4. Hide pawn on filed with id 1 and show pawn on filed with id 2
Step 5. Wait 300ms
Step 6. Hide pawn on filed with id 2 and show pawn on filed with id 3

so I wrote:

```
function movePawn(dice_result){
     setTimeout(function(){
       for(let j = 1; j <= dice_result; j++){
         sleep(300); //wait in every iteration so animation will be visible (?)
         let previous_element_id = dice_sum + j;
         let next_element_id = dice_sum + j + 1;
         document.getElementById(previous_element_id).innerHTML = '';
         document.getElementById(next_element_id).innerHTML = pawn;
       }
     dice_sum = dice_sum + dice_result;
     }, 1350); //wait until dice animation end and them start moving pawn
}

function sleep(milliseconds) {
    const date = Date.now();
    let currentDate = null;
    do {
       currentDate = Date.now();
    } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
}
```

unfortunately it shows the last step straight away

**edit:**
after changing to:

```
  function movePawn(dice_result){
    setTimeout(function(){
      for(let j = 1; j <= dice_result; j++){
        setTimeout(function(j){
          let previous_element_id = dice_sum + j;
          let next_element_id = dice_sum + j + 1;
          document.getElementById(previous_element_id).innerHTML = '';
          document.getElementById(next_element_id).innerHTML = pawn;
        }, j * 350, j); //wait before next iteration
      }
      dice_sum = dice_sum + dice_result;
    }, 1350) //wait until dice animation end and them start moving pawn
  }
```

there is still one problem: If I draw on a dice: 4 and If I stand on the field with id 0, the pawn immediately jumps to field 4 and only then moves successively by 4 fields so finally ends on field 8.

Comment: You can use `setInterval` to achieve this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately there is still one problem. If I draw on a dice: 4 and If I stand on the field with id 0, the pawn immediately jumps to field 4 and only then moves successively by 4 fields so finally ends on field 8.

Comment: Use combination of css and js... Like set transition property for your paw... After rotating dice.. Identify XY coordinates of the target TD... Set position of pawn as absolute and assign the identified coordinates to your pawn... This will give you a feel of pawn moving from SRC to target td... After transition time... You can move the pawn element to target td with styles removed... hope I conveyed thinks clearly

Comment: Be careful when you use ```setInterval``` or ```setTimeout``` with ***for*** loop.
I think, this should be helpful: https://medium.com/@axionoso/watch-out-when-using-settimeout-in-for-loop-js-75a047e27a5f

Comment: I have identified the problem it is in: 'dice_sum = dice_sum + dice_result;'. The pawn is immediately jumping to 4th field because sum is made at the very begining, but dont know why

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in `dice_sum = dice_sum + dice_result`. I have removed that line and increase dice_sum in every iteration instead at once at the end

```
 function movePawn(dice_result){
    setTimeout(function(){
      for(let j = 1; j <= dice_result; j++){
        setTimeout(function(j){
          dice_sum = dice_sum + 1;
          let previous_element_id = dice_sum;
          let next_element_id = dice_sum + 1;
          document.getElementById(previous_element_id).innerHTML = '';
          document.getElementById(next_element_id).innerHTML = pawn;
        }, j * 350, j); //wait before next iteration
      }
    }, 1350) //wait until dice animation end and them start moving pawn
  }
```